# Google Script: Retrieving Default Values for Filter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a filter for a column in a spreadsheet, then retrieve the list of default criteria values created for the filter. I believe that my code returns a Filter object without any values for it.

```
function TestFilter(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).createFilter();
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  var output = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(2).getCriteriaValues();
  return output;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "default values"?

Comment: The values that are shown by default in the dropdown menu when you create the filter manually. For example, if you have a data set that has the values ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3'], the values for the filter's drop down menu in the main sheet is '1', '2', and '3'.

Comment: You should use `getVisibleValues()`. If that doesn't work, your best option is to `getValues()` and programmatically unique them using vanilla javascript. `getCriteriaValues()` is populated only if there's a boolean criteria set: for example, when "date between" criteria is set, the criteria values would be a array of two date objects (start and end date)

Comment: Hello @Glottal, was the answer I published useful to you? I'd love to know how you moved on with the issue you originally presented. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions for this:

- [`getHiddenValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#getHiddenValues())

  > Returns the values to hide.
- [`getVisibleValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#getVisibleValues())

  > Returns the values to show.

In case your filter is set to hide all of the possible values, you will obtain what you desire by using the function `getHiddenValues()`.

However, this will not be possible if your filter is only hiding a subset of your values. For that case, you could use a Google Apps Script function such as the following below to obtain the distinct values:

```js
function getDistinctValues(range) {
  var values = range.getValues();
  var unique = {};

  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++) {
      var key = values[i][j];
      if (key !== null && key !== undefined && key !== '')
        unique[key] = true;
    }
  }

  return Object.keys(unique);
}
```

The usage of it would be, in case you were attempting to obtain the distinct values on your A column:

```js
var distinctValues = getDistinctValues(sheet.getRange("A2:A"));
```

Note that this function will return the values as Strings. In case you want to obtain the actual numeric value instead of a String, you can parse the values simply by using the following code:

```js
var distinctValues = getDistinctValues(sheet.getRange("A2:A")).map(parseFloat);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug with 2 out of 3 of these functions, by using something like this:

```
    var filter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetName").getFilter();

    var criteriaValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(9).getCriteriaValues();
    Logger.log("criteria Values length " + criteriaValues.length);
    Logger.log(criteriaValues);

    var visibleValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(9).getVisibleValues();
    Logger.log("visible Values length " + visibleValues.length);
    Logger.log(visibleValues);

    var hiddenValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(9).getHiddenValues();
    Logger.log("hidden Values length " + hiddenValues.length);
    Logger.log(hiddenValues);
```

and setting a filter on column I (9th from the left) regardless of how many or which values I filter by, I only ever see the values that I've hidden from the column, the `criteriaValues` and `visibleValues` arrays are always empty, while `hiddenValues` always shows correctly the values that are filtered out.

If someone could double check this and confirm it would be great, otherwise, maybe I'm just doing something really silly, in which case please let me know as well :).

This is created based on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria.html

> Blockquote